# Controlling/filtering user's Hive queries using Hue platform

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

Is there a way to somehow filter the user's Hive queries using the Hue platform, by configuring settings or something in order to allow a user to only execute read-only queries (like SELECT query)?

Answer (score 0):

The most used way is to rely on [Sentry](http://gethue.com/apache-sentry-made-easy-with-the-new-hue-security-app/) to set the correct SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT permissions and those will automatically apply in Hue as Hue relies on HiveServer2.